# Plucking JSON IDs out with Java Regex/Matcher API

Tags: regex, java-8

I have a Java method that will receive a minified JSON string resembling:

```
{
  "fizz": {
    "_id": "6"
  }
}
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
... (same two above objects repeated but with different values)
```

Hence minified the string would be `{"fizz":{"_id":"6"}}`. The string will be different each time the method is called (obviously) but it will adhere to the following format:

```
"CHUNK" Consists of:
{"<ANYTHING>":{"_id":"<SOME_NUMBER>"}}{<ANY_JSON_OBJECT>}
```

So as another example the method might receive the following string as input (not minifying it so as to make the example clearer):

```
{
  "fizz": {
    "_id": "6"
  }
}
{
  "foo": "bar"
}


{
  "swarm": {
    "_id": "18"
  }
}
{
  "whistle": "feather",
  "saywhat": true
}


{
  "beef": {
    "_id": "23"
  }
}
{
  "active": "NO"
}
```

I need to extract a list of all the `_id` string values in the given JSON, so in the example above, I'd want to end up with a `List<String>` containing "6", "18" and "23". My best attempt:

```
public List<String> extractIds(String json) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"_id\":.*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    while(matcher.find()) {
      ids.add("???");
    }

    return ids;
}
```

But I'm not sure whether my regex is jacked up and/or how to use the Matcher API to extract the next extracted ID in the group.

Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"_id\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

while(matcher.find()) {
    ids.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

## Explanation -

`\"_id\"` checks for the preceding `"_id"` section,
`\\s*:\\s*` checks for zero or more spaces, a colon `:`, and zero or more spaces again (I probably could have omitted the spaces part, but I am unfamiliar with JSON, so I didn't know whether there could be multiple spaces or not)
`\"(.*?)\"` creates **group 1** which contains the desired id, enclosed within `""` (If you want the double quotes in your array, then use the regex `\"_id\"\\s*:\\s*(.*?)`)

Finally, whenever we find a match for the regex, we add the contents of **group 1** to the ArrayList, using `matcher.group(1)`